# Error when trying to include ng-controller

Tags: angularjs

I am following an angular.js tutorial, and I am being thrown errors when I am trying to include 'ng-controller' in the html tag like so.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <title>Angular Js test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="static/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    <script src="static/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    <script src="static/js/angular.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
    <script src="app/controller.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="text" ng-model="name">

<h1>{{name || 'World'}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

The tutorial says to append it as a second attribute to the html tag but I am get the following errors when using it in the chrome browser

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.2/ng/areq?p0=AppCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined
    at Error (native)
    at http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:6:423
    at rb (http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:22:108)
    at Ra (http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:22:195)
    at http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:83:268
    at B (http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:61:474)
    at w (http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:62:403)
    at g (http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:56:183)
    at http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:55:329
    at http://test.dev/static/js/angular.min.js:20:103(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:111(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:84m.$apply @ angular.min.js:137(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:20e @ angular.min.js:40c @ angular.min.js:19yc @ angular.min.js:20ae @ angular.min.js:19(anonymous function) @ angular.min.js:298j @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2k.fireWith @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2m.extend.ready @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2J @ jquery-1.11.3.min.js:2
```

My Controller is as follows

```
function AppCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure which tutorial you are following, but a blank `ng-app` will not work with angular 1.3.x or higher (you appear to be trying to use 1.5.0-beta.2 here).  Also, you haven't shown enough code to do any meaningful troubleshooting.  *Usually* the error you posted here happens because you either didn't define an `AppCtrl` in JavaScript, or forgot to include a `<script>` tag in your HTML for the file that you declared it in.  However, given the use of the empty `ng-app`, it is also likely that the tutorial is using an older deprecated method for declaring controllers.

Comment: after the edit, it is clear that you are definitely using an out of date tutorial.  That syntax for declaring controllers was depreciated in 1.3.x.

Comment: HI Claies, I have edited my question to include all my code. I have tested it without using 'ng-controller' (just having a blank ng-app), and it seems to work. It is a PacktPub e book and quotes "Now that we've created our controller, we need to tell Angular we want to use it.
For our application we only need a single controller, so let's add a second attribute
to the <html> tag again:
ng-controller="AppCtrl""

Comment: Oh I just read your edit, thank you for clarifying this I think its best for me to find something a little more up to date, Thanks again!

Comment: this is documented in the angular documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration, under the section "Migrating from 1.2 to 1.3"

Comment: This is a huge help Claies, thank you for limiting my frustration!

Comment: most likely, other than the major breaking change to declarations, most of the other concepts in the book you have should still be relevant.  Just be aware that angular has a very rapid development cycle, be prepared for a few slight modifications, and you should be fine!

Comment: Awesome! I will keep this in mind going further with this. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create an app.js file

```
var app = angular.module('AppName', []);

app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = "World";
});
```

load the app.js file in your index.html file

```
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" async defer></script>
```

in your index.html file add the following to your html tag

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="AppName" ng-controller="AppCtrl">

<h1>{{ name }}</h1>
```